# When/how to unsubscribe: Management subscription in RxJS and Angular project

Tags: angular, rxjs

Here's my code snippet(example)

```
fetchData(): void {
    if (this.subscription$) {
        this.subscription$.unsubscribe();
    }
    this.subscription$ = this.store.select('someEvent')
                                   .subscribe(data => {
                                      console.log(data);
                                   });
}

ngOnDestroy() { 
  this.subscription$.unsubscribe();
}
```

I need to call the `fetchData` method to add another subscription to get the current state from `store`. So at this point, I've implemented it like above in order to free up the previous subscription. It works the way I wanted it to work but I feel like the code is not neat. I was digging into `takeUntil` and `takeWhile` to make code more `Rx` way but I didn't make it.

Comment: if your component not destroy. you have no any needs for destroy subscription. because  `this.store.select` called again and replace subscription not create new subscription.

Comment: so i think its not take new memory.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular/RxJs When should I unsubscribe from \`Subscription\`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38008334/angular-rxjs-when-should-i-unsubscribe-from-subscription)

Comment: @ShaileshLadumor I'm afraid you are wrong. I've tested it out and it subscription stays alive as I expected. Just the variable `subscription$` is replaced.

Comment: @deezg I've already checked out the question and this is a different case.

Comment: 1) why do you need to change subscription in your `fetchData` method? 2) how many different subscriptions you have that you're switching between?

Comment: @deezg I don't necessarily have to change the subscription but I implemented that way to get the current state of application from `store`. I cannot anticipate how many subscriptions would be generated. It will depend on the situation.

Comment: ok, let me rephrase: what makes you need to kill old subscription and introduce a new one? asking because, in a regular usage of the store, you don't need to do that. nor you need to 'ask for data'. that's the whole point of observable, you subscribe once and as data changes, you'll get notified. so, please explain a bit your reasons behind re-subscribing.

Comment: @deezg Okay, I think I've got your point. 1) The reason I need to kill the old subscription is otherwise, the old subscription stays alive and keeps getting the data which is likely to cause bugs. 2) I understand how observables work and the beauty of it but this case, as I explained above, I need to get the latest state/value which the `store` is keeping. In order to get it, I decide to register the subscription again because in that way, the store in Angular emits the current state which it's holding at that moment.

Comment: @deezg There may be a different way to get the current state/value of application from `store` but this approach(adding a new subscription) is what I'm taking. Walk me through if you have any idea

Comment: subscribe to your `store.select` in your constructor, so only once. within your subscribe method, you can set your private field to last received data from subscription: `...subscribe(data => { this.myData = data;})` and you'll always have last state of the store in your `this.myData` field. resubscribing over and over again you're defeating the whole purpose of observables. maybe there are some reasons for this behind my understanding, but from what i understand so far, you just don't need resubscribe at all.

Comment: btw, it sounds like there might be a need for clarification: 'old subscription' doesn't mean old data.

Comment: @deezg Actually, that's what I've tried before I took this approach. "Keeping the latest state/value in the component with a local variable". Then I was thinking, 'Is it good to keep the state/value in a component?" I understand resubscribing over times could miss the beauty of using observables. I just don't know which way is more proper.

Comment: you are not keeping state in component that way. state is kept in the store. with private field, you're using it in the component. you're just resolving (unwrapping) it from observable to usable underlying data. that is, of course, for the case you don't use `async` pipe in your template. if you were using `async` pipe, then pipe does all of that for you and you get unwrapped data ready to be used.

Comment: @deezg Understood. I guess I will need to rethink about it. Thanks man!

Comment: i'm glad if it helped. google for `dumb/smart components` in context of angular. `ngrx/store` & `async` pipes fit very nicely into that pattern and you'll get a very powerful way to build apps.

Answer (score 0):

Use a subject to signal destruction

```
destroyed$=new Subject()
 fetchData(): void {
this.store.select('someEvent').takeUntil(destroyed$)
                               .subscribe(data => {
                                  console.log(data);
                               });
}

ngOnDestroy() { 
   destroy$.next()
}
```

Comment: Appreciate your answer but the thing is I cannot wait till the component gets destroyed because the `fetchData` method is going to be called a few times, which means there will be several subscriptions alive. That's why I added `if clause` above to free up the previous one.

Comment: do you mean the code should fullfill one more requirement that only one fetchData is allow to run at any given time

Comment: No, calling the `fetchData` method several times is totally fine. What I'm wondering is if there's a way to make the unsubscribe code tidy rather than doing it manually like I did above

Comment: In a good Rxjs pattern there's should be a minimal number of subscription needed in a controller. what you normally do is return observable from function() and merge, concat them into a main function that subscribe once. If you have too many subscription sitting around often hint the code can be done better.

Comment: I understand what you mean. However, since this is just one observable called possibly over times, I cannot see any way how/why I would merge or concat them.